# General form of linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

In my textbook it says that the general form of a linear differential equation is:

> $$y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$$

But my teacher said that a linear differential equation has the general form:

> $$y'' + P(x)y' + Q(x)y = f(x)$$

Which is the correct form or they are both correct?

Comment: Both your textbook and teacher are correct. The only difference is in their orders, that is, the highest value of the derivative.

Comment: see also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda so is there a more general form that can include both versions?

Comment: The second includes the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are linear differential equations. To be more general, the general form of an order $n$ linear differential equation is
$$ y^{(n)} + \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1} P_j(x) y^{(j)} = f(x),$$
where
$$ y^{(j)} = \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right)^j y$$
is the $j$th derivative of $y$. In this terminology, your book gave the most general **first order** linear differential equation, and your teacher gave general **second order** linear differential equation.